# Trying to get the MongoDB driver working in Visual Studio 2010 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mongodb, 64-bit, mongodb-c

MongoDB driver for C++ is unbelievably complicated to work with.
I want to make a simple C++ project that inserts a row to my MongoDB instance.
I need it in a x64 ENV and in VS2010 IDE.

Do you guys maybe have the binaries of the driver or a simple example solution file with it?

The manual at Mongo's website is simply useless.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume that you tried the steps here http://www.mongodb.org/about/tutorial/build-mongodb-with-visual-studio-2010/ and something didn't work?   Maybe if you describe what problem you ran into someone can figure out what you need to do differently.

Answer (score 1):

use C# driver from here http://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp - it's easy.
C++ and C driver I can't understand too.